# how to add R package documentation to rdocumentation.org?

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I found the [rdocumentation.org](https://www.rdocumentation.org/) is a website that has the HTML documentation of many R packages, but I was confused about how it works.

Given I have an R package on GitHub, how can I have my .Rd documentation (written with Roxygen2) of this package could be searched in rdocumentation.org?

Comment: While my first suggestion would be to contact DataCamp about it (they host the site), deeper searching on the site suggests that they are no longer maintaining it. For instance, `dplyr-0.7.8` is the most recent indexed there whereas 0.8 was released in Feb 2019.

Comment: following up @r2evans's comment: the possible obsolescence of rdocumentation.org would be an even better reason to contact DataCamp about it ... I posted a question [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/fixing-r-documentation#comment-9256)

Comment: Thank you @r2evans, in that case, I also wonder if there is any other website that could host a documentation index from an R package on GitHub? I only have experience to generate the build-in documentation files (.Rd files), but also want to find a site to host the static HTML documentation.

Comment: thank you @BenBolker, do you have any other sites you would recommend for host documentation index from an R package on GitHub?

Comment: It looks like the [pkgdown package](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown) is exactly what you want (to host the package on GitHub pages)